# How to properly use self to print the string in this example

Tags: function, lua, self

In this MWE I'm trying to write a function in `lua` that when it is called it prints some text alongside the string that called the function.

For this to work I used `self` to print the string, but it actually returns a `nil` value. How do I correctly use the `self` in this example and how do I archive such task?

```
str = "Some text on the string"

function string.add()
    print("Hope it prints the string besides too",self)
end

str:add()
```

The output is the following:

> Hope it prints the string besides too   nil

What I would like to have:

> Hope it prints the string besides too   Some text on the string

Comment: Replace `function string.add()` with `function string:add()`

Comment: afaik you could also just do function string.add(self). Works for me. although that might be bad practice.

Comment: Thank you, @EgorSkriptunoff That really helped.

Comment: @Levy `function string:add()` is an other spelling for `function string.add(self)`, [see](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of your function, `string.add(self)` is equivalent to `string:add()`. In the latter version, which is a member function--or method--of the string class, `self` is the implicit first parameter. This is similar to classes in Python, where `self` is the first parameter of every member function.

```
-- Notice the self parameter.
function string.add(self)
    print("Hope it prints the string besides too", self)
    return
end

str = "Just some text on the string"
str:add()
```

As a side note, if you were to expose the items on the Lua stack through the C API when you call `str:add()`, `str` would be the first item on the stack, that is, the element at index `1`. Items are pushed on to the stack in the order that they are passed to functions.

```
print("hello", "there,", "friend")
```

In this example, `"hello"` is the first argument on the stack, `"there,"` is the second, and `"friend"` is the third. In the case of your `add` function--written as `str:add()` or `string.add(str)`--`self`, which refers to `str`, is the first item on the Lua stack. Defining member functions with the index operator, as of the form `string.add`, allows for flexibility, as one can use the form with the explicit `self` and the form with the implicit `self`.